# Find all functions $f$ such that $f(mn) = f(m)f(n)$ and...

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, contest-math, functional-equations

> Find all functions $f : N → N$ such that
>
> (a) $f(2) = 2$
>
> (b) $f(mn) = f(m)f(n)$ for all $m, n ∈ N$
>
> (c) $f(m) < f(n)$ for $m < n$

First, I substituted $m=1,n=2$ to get $f(1)=1$. Next, we can easily notice that all powers of $2$ will be equal to themselves. That is $f(4)=4,f(8)=8$, and so on. Now, the next step I'm not so sure is correct.
As $f(4)>f(3)>f(2)$, and $f : N → N$, I think $f(3)$ can only be $3$ but again I'm not so sure. If it is so, then I believe the only possible function is $f(x)=x$.

Now for the next part of the problem-

> What happens if the third condition is not given to us?

Unfortunately I don't even have the answer to the problem let alone a solution.
Any hints would also be helpful, thanks.

Comment: Note that $f(n)=f(p_1^{r_1}p_2^{r_2}\cdots p_k^{r_k})=f(p_1)^{r_1}\cdots f(p_k)^{r_k}$. So, the function is completely specified if we know it's values on primes. Now, if the third condition doesn't exist, just assign random values to the primes. Each one leads to a new function.

Comment: @Umesh Shankar got it, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

More easily :

if $f(1)=1$ and $f(2^n)=2^n$, and because you have
$$1 =f(1) < f(2) < f(3) < f(4) < ... < f(2^n)=2^n$$

the only possibility is that $f(2)=2$, $f(3)=3$, $f(4)=4$ and so on.

Comment: Can't believe I almost did the whole question only to miss something so simple as noticing that $f(5)$ also had to equal 5 because each number needs to have a corresponding value at the end

Comment: There is a follow up question to this, do you mind if I ask you that (or maybe I'll just edit the question to include it actually)